# Hello Watch 3+ smart watch firmware extracting

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, firmware-analysis, binary-format, binwalk

I have a firmware file of Hello Watch 3+ smart watch. I want to customize this firmware. I tried binwalk but no result. I am trying reverse engineering for the first time. Can you help me?

File link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/70u7tsa6k2rvjul/M78_4.00.13_231205.bin/file

[image: the entropy results]

```
$ binwalk -Me M78_4.00.13_231205.bin                   

Scan Time:     2023-12-07 06:37:15
Target File:   /home/kali/Desktop/bins/M78_4.00.13_231205.bin
MD5 Checksum:  e39e4a9488b26196bc9bde668502284f
Signatures:    411

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe upload the file somewhere so people can take a look at it.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/70u7tsa6k2rvjul/M78_4.00.13_231205.bin/file

Comment: Where did you get the file from? For a complete firmware (OS) it is rather small. If you open the file with a  hexeditor you can see that it contains multiple sections and strings (like uboot).

Comment: Hello Watch 3+ V4.0 : https://bucolic-chaja-410e56.netlify.app/#/

When I open it with the hex editor, I see a bunch of nonsense, meaningless characters. Can you take a look?

Comment: Scroll through it or run strings. In particular at the beginning and end you find something. I still doubt this is the complete firmware. Just a guess but maybe it is an incremental update.